# Javascript splice method issue with this

Tags: javascript, array-splice

I will be happy if someone could help me with my problem :

I'm trying to delete the current max number form the nums Array and I couldn't get it done.

```js
function getNthLargestNum(nums, nth) {
  debugger;
  var maxNums = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < nth; i++) {
    var nthMax = 0;
    var maxTemp = 0;

    for (var j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if (maxTemp < nums[j]) {
        maxTemp = nums[j];
        //splice();
      }
    }
    nums.splice(maxTemp, maxTemp[j]);
    maxNums.push(maxTemp);
  }
  nthMax = maxTemp;
  return nthMax;
}
var nums = [4, 5, 6, 8, 40, 60, 54, 32, 8, 1];
//var nums = [4 , 5 , 6 , 8 , 40 , 3 , 8 , 1];
var res = getNthLargestNum(nums, 3);
``
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It's not clear what your expected output is. Does your array have to stay in the same order because there are easier ways if not.

Comment: please add a wanted output.

Comment: `maxTemp[j]` makes no sense. `maxTemp` is a number, not an array.

Comment: `getNthLargestNum` doesn't make sense in context of the question too. Are you meant to be returning them or deleting them?

Comment: sorry , i need to get the 3rd largest number that is : 40 at this code ,

Comment: and i want to delete the current max number in the array by one iteration

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to `splice()` are the array index to start removing from, and the number of elements to remove. `maxTemp` is an array value, not an index, anx `maxTemp[j]` is completely meaningless since `maxTemp` isn't an array.

You need to use another variable to hold the index where the maximum element was found. Every time you update `maxTemp`, you also update `maxIndex` with the current index. Then you use this in the splice.

There doesn't seem to be any need for the `maxNums` array; you push onto it, but never use it for anything. And `nthMax` just holds the last value of `maxTemp` before you return it -- you can simply return `maxTemp` itself.

```js
function getNthLargestNum(nums, nth) {
  debugger;
  var nthMax;
  for (var i = 0; i < nth; i++) {

    var maxTemp = nums[0];
    var maxIndex = 0;
    for (var j = 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
      if (maxTemp < nums[j]) {
        maxTemp = nums[j];
        maxIndex = j;
      }
    }
    nums.splice(maxIndex, 1);
  }
  return maxTemp;
}
var nums = [4, 5, 6, 8, 40, 60, 54, 32, 8, 1];
//var nums = [4 , 5 , 6 , 8 , 40 , 3 , 8 , 1];
var res = getNthLargestNum(nums, 3);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to return the first of nth largest numbers you can simply do this:

```
function getNthLargestNum(nums, nth) {
  return nums.slice(0).sort((a, b) => b - a)[nth - 1];
}

var nums = [4, 5, 6, 8, 40, 60, 54, 32, 8, 1];
getNthLargestNum(nums, 3); // 40
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r8hx3s55/3/)